# Foreground app being killed when screen is off

Tags: android, ram, battery, foreground

I have a problem on my android phone where the app that I'm running in the foreground is getting killed if the screen is off. Examples include: listning to a podcast with stitcher, using voice mavigation with google maps, having an ongoing call using a voip app, listning to an audio book with audible.

Apps get killed off at some random point when the screen is off. e.g. sometimes it'll happen after a minute, sometimes i'll be 30 mins in a drive and a podcast will just cut out. After this happens, if I unlock my phone, I'm back on my home screen.

Things I have tried:

- restarting my phone more regularly, no benefit
- pin the foreground app before turning off the screen. no benefit.
- Uninstalling apps / stopping background services to reduce RAM usage. I initially blamed RAM, but I've uninstalled a bunch of things and it's been no help.

Other information about my phone:

- LG G7 (LM-G710EMW), Android version 9, kernel version 4.9.112
- Developer options -> running services: usually shows plenty of free RAM (e.g. right now, 1.2GB free). When stitcher appears on this list, it uses about 250mb.
- Using nova launcher
- Not using any third party battery saving / optimization apps. All apps mentioned have been selected in Settings -> Battery -> 'Power saving exclusions' for android's built in battery. Android's built in battery saver is turned off.
- Not using any third party apps that kill other apps, claim to free up RAM, etc. The only thing I have that could be killing other apps is tasker.

So this is super annoying because it basically prevents me from using the phone for anything useful unless I keep the screen on. I know I can darken the screen as much as possible, so keeping the screen on reduces battery drain, this is ok for navigation but not good enough for when you want to keep your phone in your pocket.

I was blaming RAM - i.e. somehow I'm running out of RAM and android is killing the app that's using the most. But it makes no sense to kill the foreground app.

Open to any and all suggestions, even if it's a long shot.

I'm not concerned about battery life at all. If there's any other battery saving / optimization features I can turn off, I'm all for it.

Comment: Did you activated `Developer options` on the phoe? If you did then please check `Don't keep activities` option. Switching off `Don't keep activities` may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've checked and that setting is already off.

Answer (score -1):

Because of [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background).To keep your app not being killed you have to create a foreground services

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how this is relevant at all. I'm not writing an app, I'm having this problem with using existing apps like google maps. As I explained in my question, these apps are not running in the background at all, this is the foreground app.

Comment: your app is not foreground when screen is off

Comment: Ok, I guess I don't quite understand what foreground/background is. Do you have any suggestions on what I can do to fix this as an app user? These are popular apps, so I think it's more the problem is with my phone / phone settings, rather than with the app itself. I assume if something like a 'foreground service' was required, google maps would be doing it already...

Comment: https://stitcher.helpshift.com/a/stitcher/?s=current-known-issues&f=android---frequent-pausing&p=all